# Verify if user has account in my app with iCloud auth approach

Tags: android, ios, authentication, icloud

I have just read an article where it was explained how to get the token from iCloud in order to execute authentication with the iOS platform.

How can we combine Android and iOS with such an approach?

How Android will know that user has iOS account?

Which kind of credentials do I need to ask users to verify if they already have an account on the iOS platform?

Answer (score 0):

Aleksey,

This code, confirms somebody is logged into iCloud by trying to access an iCloudKit container. The first method checks and sends a notification if it if it fails, the second method trigger by said failure shunts the user to the control panel so they can sign into iCloud.

```
 func isAuthorized4Cloud() {
    container = CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.X")
    publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase
    privateDB = container.privateCloudDatabase
    var userID: CKRecordID!
    container.fetchUserRecordID( completionHandler: { recordID, error in
        if error == nil {
            userID = recordID
            print("files_setup userID \(userID.recordName)")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("cloudConnected"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
        } else {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("noCloud"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
            print("files_setup \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

In your view Controller...

```
  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(noCloud), name: Notification.Name("noCloud"), object: nil)

  func noCloud(notification:NSNotification) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.navigation.isHidden = true
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Stop", message: "Sorry, you need to log into iCloud ...", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
            guard let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
                return
            }

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                    print("Settings opened: \(success)") // Prints true
                })
            }
        }
        alert.addAction(settingsAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it is very helpful , but question was about, try to imagine for example I downloaded the app on my iOS and made auth, now you as a owner has my account in DB, than I took my android device , downloaded the same app and ... ? Which kind of credentials I am as a user have to fill in to make you as a owner of app  understand that I am it is the same user that has already has account with iOS platform? And I need to get the same my account to my android from ios... Did you get my idea?

Comment: Aleksey I am sorry I am iOS guy, I know very little about Android authentication.

Comment: thats noting, I am just wondering how does it have to work with multi platforms... If apple produce this way for auth it means that it should be a way to apply it for android. Because other way it means that I as dev need to provide two different auth form , one for iOS another for android , but worse another I need to provide two DB also. For example how work google auth it is very clear and does not matter which platform are you using it is work the same, did you get my idea?